# How do I ask my manager about switching out of my current team?

Tags: professionalism, communication, management, team

My team is not a good fit for me due to no communication among other issues. I've clicked really well with another team and am interested in their work.

What's the best way to be professional about this with my current manager who will not want me transferring?

Comment: Thanks for cleaning the rant :) welcome to The Workplace BTW... cleaning my comments shortly...

Comment: The way to be professional was to let your manager know before you got the ball rolling.

Comment: I am sorry but I strongly disagree with the edit you made sushicat, if we look at the question and some of the answers (like, Kilisi's one) we clearly see there is a hole of information about what happened. Please reinsert the part about where you talk to others teammates and that their manager contact yours before you could talk to her.

Answer (score 9):

You're on the wrong team. You have requested a move to a different team where you would feel more comfortable. A reasonable, accommodating company will honor the request and help you succeed. A disreputable company will keep you on your current team and hold you back. The burden is on the company, not you. I've been working eighteen years, and over half the companies weren't worth my time and effort. Keep speaking up and trying to create positive change and you'll be fine. If you find yourself no better in a month or two, move on to a different organization. Life is too short to waste your time working for a manager who doesn't respect you.

Answer (score 2):

Too late to worry about being professional now, you have already bad mouthed your current team to another and gotten a ball rolling without your managers knowledge.

Best thing now is to just sit it out quietly and let it take it's course.

Answer (score 2):

> Least said, soonest mended.

Though this is not always true, I think in your case, this is good advice.  Attempting to approach your manager at this point will simply aggravate matters, since it will show that you feel almost as though you did something wrong by not giving them a heads up, even though you couldn't help it.

Since you did nothing wrong, you're better off just to act in exactly that way and not try playing with fire.

If you do say something about it to your manager (for instance, if they ask), make it totally casual.  Something along the lines of,

> Oh, yes, I meant to let you know I was applying for a transfer, but it went a lot faster than I expected, so I didn't have time.